# Ubuntu 16.04 KVM PCI PassThrough

Tags: nvidia, gpu, qemu

Okay, so I'm not sure where to start. I am attempting to setup PCI GPU Passthrough for a Nvidia GTX 1080ti FE on a Dell R710 server for computing. I am trying to pass it through to a Win 7 VM using VFIO and OVMF on the VM but I have to be missing something as the device causes Win 7 to fail to boot once I remove all devices and attach the GPU. It is at least passing through the display through the gpu which is a start but not complete. I have my VM XML listed in the below Pastebin as well as a screenshot. I attempted to use this step-by-step: https://medium.com/@calerogers/gpu-virtualization-with-kvm-qemu-63ca98a6a172

I have the listing below in my grub file to use for the pass-through on the devices.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.blacklist=1 vfio-pci.ids=10de:1b06,10de:10ef intel_iommu=on vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1"
```

I then verified that the devices are using the VFIO drivers:

```
VirtServer:~$ lspci -nnk
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b06] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:120f]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
07:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10ef] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:120f]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

and i also

So. What am I missing in my config that would be causing these issues? Thanks in Advance!!

XML File - https://pastebin.com/dJDkWeNf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling remote access first, then adding the the gpu after all that is set up?

I'm working on something similar, except with a FirePro V3900 on